# Plugin daterangepicker doesn't check date valid value

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I use this plugin: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

I need a input field where **I can select a single date**, **or leave empty**. If I insert **invalid date the plugin need to correct it itself**.

I've create a jsfiddle to report the problem:

FIRST INPUT EXAMPLE : This input field version works great, but I can't empty the field If need it. God part is that if I insert a invalid date manually, the field autocorrect itself!

SECOND INPUT EXAMPLE: In this input field I can empty the field if I need, BUT if i wrote invalid date manually, the invalid value remain!! I'd like the plugin checks for validity on trigger change!

This is my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k15vzajd/2/

Code used:

```
$("#data2").daterangepicker({
        "showISOWeekNumbers": true,
        "autoApply": true,
        "autoUpdateInput": false,
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "locale": {
        "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Applica",
            "cancelLabel": "Annulla",
            "fromLabel": "Da",
            "toLabel": "A",
            "customRangeLabel": "Personalizza",
            "weekLabel": "W",
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "Do",
                "Lu",
                "Ma",
                "Me",
                "Gi",
                "Ve",
                "Sa"
            ],
            "monthNames": [
                "Gennaio",
                "Febbraio",
                "Marzo",
                "Aprile",
                "Maggio",
                "Giugno",
                "Luglio",
                "Agosto",
                "Settembre",
                "Ottobre",
                "Novembre",
                "Dicembre"
            ],
            "firstDay": 1
        }
    }, function(start_date, end_date) {
        this.element.val(start_date.format('DD/MM/YYYY')).trigger("change");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line to prevent default behaviour:

```
  $('#data1, #data2').on('keydown', function(event){
        // allow "back" key
        keycode = event.keyCode || event.which
        if(keycode!=8) event.preventDefault();
  })
```

now only input via the datepicker calendar is possible, or clearing the input field with the back key. note: the jsfiddle uses the configuration of the 2nd datepicker for both, `$data1` and `#data2`.

see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cjfswnrx/

or you can use the default configuration of the plugin, which allows you to manually edit a date and autocorrects itself:

```
$("#data1, #data2").daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    minYear: 1901,
    maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'),10),
    // your locale settings
```

https://jsfiddle.net/36ybpd50/

Comment: workaroud is god but...i can't write a date manually... only use calendar.

Comment: ok, but to have a datepicker in the first place is to pick a date? right?

Comment: btw.: you can add this line to the keydown event: `$(this).val('')`, then any keystroke empties the input field

Comment: yes right, but some users select a default date (today) and modify manually adding for example 10 years....and do it manually change only year to speedup

Comment: just update example and added jsfiddle with original datepicker config, that should do it?

Comment: no still doesn't work: if i accidentally write "08/10/2019FF" and click outside the calendar, the input remain "08/10/2019FF" that is a NON valid date...